# How do I add fragment identifiers to the page URL based on UpdatePanel content in ASP .NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, uri

I am creating a web application in ASP .NET (C#), using WebForms. I have a single page `Default.aspx`, which has in it an `UpdatePanel`, and some buttons outside the `UpdatePanel` which trigger an async postback to update the `UpdatePanel`. Now, the `UpdatePanel` content depends on which button triggered the async postback.

What I wish to achieve is that a fragment identifier must get attached to the page URL depending on the current content of the `UpdatePanel`, so that when the user clicks the back button on the browser, there will be an async postback request and the previous content will load again, instead of navigating away from the entire page.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This article may be helpful http://magnuskragelund.dk/url-with-hash-mark-changing-after-partial-postback/